# No iAd in iTunesConnect

Tags: app-store-connect, iad

Want iAd in app. So can't find how to add iAd in iTunesConnect. There are only paid and free application types.

[image]

How to request iAd type?

Comment: iAd is disconitnued.. try using Admob or other ad providers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iAd App Network was discontinued as of June 30, 2016.